# Bash + Kubectl - Wait till all pods are in Running

Tags: bash, kubectl

I am creating pods in kubernetes environment on linux machine.
I would like to wait till all pods are in Running state. I have written while loop in bash but it is still looping even the podstatus (variable) does not have "false" value in it.
Thanks for any help!

---

```
verifyPods(){
   timer=0
   msg="false"
   while [[ $timer -lt 15 &&  "false"  == *"$msg"* ]] ;do
        sleep 10
        ((timer=timer+1))
        echo "Timer current value >> $timer and Pods statuses >> $podstatus"
        podstatus=$(kubectl -n $ns get pods -o custom columns=metadata.name:status.containerStatuses[*].ready | grep true)
       echo "Pod status is >> $podstatus and Timer is >> $timer"
  done
}



Printed Output:
Pod status is >> true
true
true
true,true
true
true,true
true
true and Timer is >> 14
Timer current value >> 15 and Pod statuses >> true
true
```

Comment: You could count the number of "false" matches with:   grep -c false   and adjust the while loop with that value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative approach is to use [`kubectl wait`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait)

You could:

```bash
kubectl wait pod \
--all \
--for=condition=Ready \
--namespace=${ns}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - Added timeout flag to avoid infinite loop.    kubectl wait pod --all --for=condition=Ready --namespace=$ns --timeout=60s

Answer (score 0):

As @S_IROTHI mentioned in the comment, Use `kubectl get pods | grep -c "Running"` to get the number of the pods with **Running status** and create a while loop to check the number of running pods with existing pods as follows

```
verifyPods(){
pods_count=$(kubectl get pods -n $namespace | grep -c "Running")

while [ $pods_count -ne $(kubectl get pods -n $namespace | grep -c "")]
do
 echo "waiting for all pods to be ready"
 sleep 10
done

echo "All pods are ready"
}
```